# Adal to Msal conversion -> JWT token validation

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, jwt, azure-ad-msal, bearer-token

I have registered `xyz.com` domain in Azure Active Directory. Then I registered a React single page app in Azure AD App registrations.

I am using `domain_name/AllowAnonymous` (http://example.com/user_impersonation) scope in react app to generate a token using msal-react.

The generated token from react app contains `domain_name/AllowAnonymous` (http://example.com/user_impersonation) as audience in JWT token claims.

In the backend, I am using client-id (api://<client-id/Allow.AllUsers>) as audience in JWT token validator to validate token.

But token has `domain_name/AllowAnonymous` (http://example.com/user_impersonation) as audience, due to which the token validation fails.

How can I get the `domain_name` by client-id in backend C# code to validate token by `domain_name`?

Is it secure to set client_id as scope in front-end application for generating JWT token?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can configure the app based on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-react

Client_Id is a public information, you can add it to the web app with no worry.

Also keep in mind that in the Azure Active Directory are 3 types of tokens: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/develop/security-tokens

If you need to validate the token, take a look of the examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code